# Kernel compilation failed

Tags: kernel

I'm trying the cuda in mathematica 11.1. The cuda functions seems to work fine. The CUDAFluidDynamics[], runs the example simulation, although I am not certain if it runs on the device or the host.

However, I get an error message when trying to use the cuda link:

```
 fun=CUDAFunctionLoad["__global__ void zero(mint * in, mint length) {
    mint index = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    if (index < length)
       in[index] = 0;
    }", "zero",{{_Integer},_Integer},{10},ShellOutputFunction->Print]
```

CUDAFunctionLoad::cmpf: The kernel compilation failed. Consider setting 
   the option "ShellOutputFunction"->Print to display the compiler error 
   message.

C:\Users\cris\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\ApplicationData\CUDALink\BuildFolder\cris-i7-17020\Working-cris-i7-17020-1560-3>call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64 
nvcc fatal   : Value 'sm_61' is not defined for option 'gpu-architecture'

It seems that the value sm61 is causing the problems, How do I solve it?

Comment: Have you tried specifying a different architecture, e.g. `"CUDAArchitecture" -> "sm_52"` ?

Comment: It gives me the same error message: nvcc fatal   : Value 'sm52' is not defined for option \
'gpu-architecture'

Comment: I am using a GTX 1050.

Comment: What does `"Description" /. CUDAResourcesInformation[]` give?

Comment: {{Name -> CUDAResources, Version -> 10.5.0, BuildNumber -> , 
    Qualifier -> Win64, WolframVersion -> 10.5+, 
    SystemID -> {Windows-x86-64}, 
    Description -> {ToolkitVersion -> 7.0, MinimumDriver -> 300.0}, 
    Category -> , Creator -> , Publisher -> , Support -> ,Internal -> False, Location -> 
 C:\Users\cris\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Paclets\Repository\CUDAResources-Win64-10.5.0, Context -> {}, Enabled -> True, 
 Loading -> Manual, Hash -> 79fa747a52a45bf2d78e2c3516c80061}}

Comment: In the information there is something wrong as well:   "Multiprocessor Count" -> 5,  and  "Compute Capabilities" -> 6.1.

Comment: I wonder if the toolkit version is too old to support the card. Have you tried updating `CUDAResourcesInstall[Update -> True]`

Comment: Yes, I tryied it, but not sure it worked because the kernel stopped after downloading the update.  Probably I had to delete the paclet by myself and try to update it again.